# Python Socket Programming Client "quit not working

Tags: python, sockets

I made a simple Chat Server using Python. I'm having trouble quitting the program from the client side. When connected I need to be able to type "/quit" and the program should disconnect from both sides, client and server. here is my code:

```
alias= raw_input("Name: ")
print 'Connected to remote host. You can start sending messages'
sys.stdout.write(alias + '->'); sys.stdout.flush()

while 1:
    socket_list = [sys.stdin, s]

    # Get the list sockets which are readable
    read_sockets, write_sockets, error_sockets = 
        select.select(socket_list , [], [])

    for sock in read_sockets:
        if sock == s:
            # incoming message from remote server, s
            data = sock.recv(4096)
            print data
            if not data :
                print '\nServer has ended Connection'
                sys.exit()

            else :
                #print data
                sys.stdout.write(data)
                sys.stdout.write(alias + '->'); sys.stdout.flush()

        else :
            # user entered a message
            msg = alias + '->' + sys.stdin.readline()
            quit = '/quit'

            #print msg == quit
            print
            if msg is quit:
                print "Goodbye"
                s.close()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                s.send(msg)
                sys.stdout.write(alias + '->')
                sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `if msg is quit` should be `if msg == quit`. `is` tests for identity, not equality. If you were testing if two objects were the same, you would use `is` here. However since you are comparing two strings, you must use `==`.

Also, your `msg` variable is equal to `alias + -> + readline`. therefore `"name -> /quit"` will never equal `'/quit'`.

Comment: Yeah,unfortunately I tried that when testing. I seems there is a problem with my comparion as it just prints /quit back to the server